# Check file type, return url if image, else return file if pdf

Tags: android, image, file-type

I have an API that returns the following:

```
"attachment": {
        "original": "......"
    }
```

This can be an image, a pdf, a word file, etc. Here are some examples:

```
"attachment": {
            "original": "/attachment/sample_pdf_file.pdf"
        }

"attachment": {
            "original": "/attachment/sample_image.jpg"
        }

// Etc.
```

My question is, how should I go about checking this and returning it to my adapter? If it's an image I want to use `Picasso` to upload the image, if it's a PDF then I want to use something else to show a pdf, and so on.

My thought process is that I should make a `Model` and a `Util` class for this.

So it would look something like this:

**Model**

```
public class Attachment {

    @SerializedName("original")
    private String mOriginal;
    public String getOriginal() { return mOriginal; }

}
```

**Utility**

```
public class AttachmentUtil {

    // Code to check stuff here

}
```

How should I go about checking this properly?

Comment: You can download the file to a temp directory, then use Bitmap decodeFile to load the file, but with the option inJustDecodeBounds set to true, if it's non-null, it's a valid picture. The option is not required but strongly recommended, you don't want to load the whole picture into memory.

Comment: Isn't this resource expensive on a mobile device?

Comment: It's wrong approach because i.e. `decodeFile()` can fail for other reasons so drawing conclusion that `if it filed then it is PDF` makes no logical reason. It's just wrong :)

Comment: Thus the inJustDecodeBounds option, only the out fields will be filled, no memory for the bitmap will be allocated. See the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds

Comment: @Marcin Orlowsky It is certainly better than looking for an extension (which can be jpeg, bmp, png etc.), and if it failed to load for ANY reason, he shouldn't care, it shouldn't be treated like a picture then (if he did, he'd might try to do some preview, which would fail as well)

Comment: Also, I made a small mistake, decodeFile() will NOT return null if it was loaded, it will return a bitmap, but only the out field will be valid, so he can do detailed validity checks as well.

Comment: @AdnanElezovic disagree. It solves nothing, because it can tell if it is picture or not. And if it is not a picture you still do not know what it potentially can be. So name checking may work better regarding of its simplicity. But in my answer I suggest API based solution which IMHO is the right way to go if possible.

Comment: The original question is how to determine if the file is a PDF, a picture, or something completely else. Loading the bounds of the bmp is very cheap and fast, if it failed then load the first few bytes of the file which are standardized for the pdf ("%PDF".bytes()), if it's nothing of these two, then it is something else. This is the safest way, no matter what file name you set.

Comment: @AdnanElezovic if you think that is good answer, why not write an answer? I can test out which of the answers is more efficient. I'm also writing up my own answer right now.

Comment: Comparing them would be like having 2 algorithms that identify if something is a person or not, where yours just checks if it's a siluete, while mine checks exactly if it's 100% a human body. But very well, I will put up a snippet in a few minutes. Yours will obviously be faster, but will fail on scenarios like "aPdfFile.jpg" and "myImage.pdf"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd fix the API to provide such information in returned data set:

```
"attachment": {
        "original": "/attachment/sample_pdf_file.pdf",
        "original_type": "pdf"
    }

"attachment": {
        "original": "/attachment/sample_image.jpg",
        "original_type": "jpg"
    }
```

but if you got no control over it, it most likely should be sufficient to check file name of your `original`. If so called "extension" is `.pdf` then it is PDF, if it is `.jpg` then it JPEG and so on. Or, cleaner way, use existing methods:
[guessContentTypeFromName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName%28java.lang.String%29) or [guessContentTypeFromStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromStream%28java.io.InputStream%29). But again - fix the API if you can.

Comment: I have control over it so not a bad idea. What would you suggest the API should return?

Comment: Still confused could you write that in `JSON`? I'll have to edit the endpoints myself, so a `JSON` format would help a lot. Possible include that as an edit in your post.

Comment: Okay! Looking into guessContentTypeFromName() and the other method now. I'll except this answer if everything looks good.

Comment: Which language is API written in?

Comment: As I can see you can have some libs that can detect file type **by content** (not file name), so use in on API side. The benefit is you will do this only once, on upload to API side and most likely store in DB, which will be always better than doing this on client side (w/o cache you will be doing this each time you "see" given fine, not matter you already "saw" and detected its type dozens of time.

Comment: Why not use the following method: `url.subString(url.lastIndexOf("."));` to check for extension? Isn't that more resource inexpensive? I'll look into libraries for the Rails API.

Comment: What if name got no dot at all or not "extension"? Use right tool for the task :) That's why you should do it by content :)

Comment: Do it the right way -> check by content. Really. Trust me.

Comment: URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName() is limited in its scope and I believe it is not able to identify application/pdf files. Will test it out regardless.